# SQL - Converting static pivot into dynamic pivot

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, pivot, pivot-table, dynamic-pivot

I have the following static pivot that works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM

(

SELECT

 d.CODE,
 a.ANAPARA - Isnull(b.ANAPARA,0) AS ANAPARA,
 d.NAME_,
 c.DUEDATE,
 a.TAKSIT - Isnull(b.TAKSIT,0) AS TAKSIT,
 e.CURCODE



FROM
    (SELECT 
 PARENTREF,
 SUM(TOTAL) AS ANAPARA,
 SUM(INTTOTAL) AS FAIZ,
 SUM(BSMVTOTAL) AS BSMV,
 SUM(KKDFTOTAL) AS KKDF,
 SUM(TOTAL+INTTOTAL+BSMVTOTAL+KKDFTOTAL) AS TAKSIT

        FROM LG_011_BNCREPAYTR 
        WHERE TRANSTYPE = 0 
        GROUP BY PARENTREF) a 

LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
 PARENTREF,
 SUM(TOTAL) AS ANAPARA,
 SUM(INTTOTAL) AS FAIZ,
 SUM(BSMVTOTAL) AS BSMV,
 SUM(KKDFTOTAL) AS KKDF,
 SUM(TOTAL+INTTOTAL+BSMVTOTAL+KKDFTOTAL) AS TAKSIT
        FROM LG_011_BNCREPAYTR 
        WHERE TRANSTYPE = 1 
        GROUP BY PARENTREF) b 
ON a.PARENTREF = b.PARENTREF

INNER JOIN (SELECT
 PARENTREF,
 CREDITREF,
 DUEDATE,
 OPRDATE
 FROM LG_011_BNCREPAYTR) c
ON a.PARENTREF=c.PARENTREF

INNER JOIN LG_011_BNCREDITCARD d
ON c.CREDITREF=d.LOGICALREF

INNER JOIN L_CURRENCYLIST e
ON d.TRCURR=e.CURTYPE OR (d.TRCURR=0 AND e.CURTYPE=160)

WHERE e.FIRMNR=11

) x
PIVOT
(
SUM(TAKSIT)
FOR CURCODE IN ([USD],[EUR],[YEN])

) xx
```

It creates the following table:

```
CODE      ANAPARA             NAME_          DUEDATE          EUR        USD        YEN
 001       103.35          CAR LOAN       2015-01-01         NULL     150.01       NULL   
 002       106.89     CONSUMER LOAN       2015-03-10       190.35       NULL       NULL
 003       110.44          CAR LOAN       2015-04-20         NULL       NULL     200.51
 004       103.22          CAR LOAN       2015-05-04       150.02       NULL       NULL
```

However, I would like to convert it into a dynamic pivot. Hence, I would like to change the code so that it gets the distinct currency codes from `e.CURCODE` and produces the same pivot table.

THANKS A LOT.

Comment: Search this site for dynamic pivot. You will find that it has been answered dozens and dozens of times.

Comment: I understand, but I am new to the dynamic functionalities of SQL and do not know where to start. I have gone through few examples, but could not implement them in my code. For instance, I do not know why they use the ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',' , '') + QUOTENAME(...) statement. I get errors when I try to integrate somebody else's solutions into my code.

Comment: here is an example of using sp_executesql:  http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/

Comment: I am not a huge fan of using PIVOT. I prefer cross tabs. I find them easier to code and understand plus they are generally slightly faster than PIVOT. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/ http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

Comment: The results valus are useless without the base data